# How make access to domain or subdomain for 1 IP on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, ip, whitelist

Hello how make access to domain for 1 static IP on Laravel?

I know need use array and`$request->ip();`

Comment: You could also change your .htaccess file to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware). It serves as a wall between your request and controllers. Example middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FilterIps
{
    const ALLOWED = [
        '100.100.100.100',
    ];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        abort_unless(in_array($request->ip(), self::ALLOWED), 403);
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Example way to activate it is to put it in `web` array in `$middlewareGroups` variable inside your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\FilterIps;

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
        FilterIps::class,
    ],

    // ...
];
```

Comment: Thank you. I try make route with this but get mistake on this.

Comment: If you have any more questions, you can ping me :)

Comment: I new here :) what mean @ping me@ :) Yes I have about route - have trable

Comment: To ping someone means to tag someone e.g. @Tony Can you explain your issue with route?

Comment: Any more details?